# ValueError: A non-empty list of tiles should be provided to merge

Tags: python, openstreetmap, cartopy

Can someone help me figure out the error message while using cartopy?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.inset_locator import inset_axes
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt

import windrose

ws = np.random.random(500) * 6
wd = np.random.random(500) * 360

minlon, maxlon, minlat, maxlat = (6.5, 7.0, 45.85, 46.05)

proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
# Draw main ax on top of which we will add windroses
main_ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=proj)
main_ax.set_extent([minlon, maxlon, minlat, maxlat], crs=proj)
main_ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
main_ax.coastlines()

request = cimgt.OSM()
main_ax.add_image(request, 12)
```

The error I receive is `ValueError: A non-empty list of tiles should be provided to merge.`
and can't seem to figure out what's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is rejected by OSM server. To get around it, you need to use `image_spoof()` as demonstrated
in this [link](https://makersportal.com/blog/2020/4/24/geographic-visualizations-in-python-with-cartopy).

With `image_spoof()` in place, your relevant code should be:-

```
# reformat web request for street map spoofing
cimgt.OSM.get_image = image_spoof
# continued with your code
request = cimgt.OSM() # spoofed
```

Comment: Thank you! The link you shared was very helpful!